# Automating filter rule creation in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I get cases where I start getting e-mails from people I am not interested in getting.

These are not SPAM, just boring e-mails.

In such cases I tend to create the filter rule that makes all the emails of that person go outside the inbox and into some label.

The problem is that the process it takes to create the filter each time is long.  Is there a way to make that filter creation faster?

Comment: Great question. But just how often do you need to create a pair of label/filter? In other words, how do you get email from so many boring sources?

Comment: They ask me question through my blog.  I answer, and then they add me to some boring mailing list they have.  I started answering people less because of it - but had hopped for a better solution...

Answer (score 4):

Both the individual message action menu ([image: Individual message menu]) and the More Actions menu ([image: More actions]) have a `Filter message like these` option.  You can do this from an individual thread or select multiple emails and use the More Actions menu.

There isn't any way to send these into an existing filter without going through the long edit process.

Comment: Damn.  That is what I feared.

Answer (score -1):

I often times wish I could highlight an email and create a filter that archives it with one button. Most users don't even know what filters are, and they don't know to go to More Actions->Filter Messages like these.  Then they have to click next, and select what they want to do with that mail.  The critical step is them deciding what they want to do with that mail.  This could be expedited with a simple "Sort to" menu.  A user could then sort that sender to trash, a new filter automatically titled by the name of the sender, add it to another filter.  This would really empower me and other users to really take control of our inbox.

Please join the group and post a reply of at least "like"

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gmail-labs-suggest-a-labs-feature/I41-Hoq6HeM/spubj90JEYcJ